# Detect in c# winforms program when user start another exe file / program

Tags: c#

I am developing an antiheat c# program that communicates with my game server. The program when started needs to check started programs and scan for bad ones. Also it needs to scan the started programs continuously, because users can run exe applications to cheat in game.

The problem is that programs can be rewritten (aimbot.exe to  something.exe) so the detection can't be done by name.
How could I detect active running programs? Also would it be viable to find exe files from open programs, then get the MD5 hash from those exe files and compare them to a list of known cheat programs? Is it possible, or there is a better solution?

EDIT:
The main problem is AimBot - it is an application designed to automatically aim at a player, you just need to press left mouse button to shoot, and every hit is 100% accurate. My program is for a mod Gta San Andreas Multiplayer, so is there a way maybe to detect if some application attaches to the game?

Comment: That looks like a hiding to nothing to me. I'd be looking at what the cheat programs did to my server, and then securing it against that sort of behaviour.

Comment: Well Tony, I have basically everything covered server-side, but the main problem is AimBot - it is an application designed to automatically aim at a player, you just need to press left mouse button to shoot, and every hit is 100% accurate. My program is for a mod Gta San Andreas Multiplayer, so is there a way maybe to detect if some application attaches to the game?

Comment: The interception of a program that is currently starting can be done using [Windows Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188966.aspx), but hooks are not a [trivial matter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get a list of the currently running processes using the [Process.GetProcesses()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
try
{           
    var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (var process in processes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", process.Id, process.ProcessName));
        Console.WriteLine(process.MainModule.FileName);
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
}
```

Using the `Process` object, you could retrieve information like full file name, type, start time, and so on, in order to calculate the check sum from the file size for example.

You can calculate the [MD5 hash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example for the process name using the [MD5 ComputeHash()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like this:

```
try
{           
    var md5 = MD5.Create();
    var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (var process in processes)
    {
        var md5Hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(process.ProcessName));
        var md5HashAsBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(md5Hash);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}", process.Id, process.ProcessName, md5HashAsBase64));
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
}
```

You can pull the list of the running processes constantly with the above code, or you could *intercept* the creation/start of new processes using windows hook. The problem is, that the second option is not an easy matter. You could find more info about hooks: [here - Hooks in Visual Studio with C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804), [Windows hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and here [Windows Hooks with .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188966.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. Will I be able to get MD5 hash from exe files via the first metod? I am really new to C# programming.

Comment: Yes, i update my example to calculate the MD5 hash for every process name from the list.

Comment: Glad that the answer helped.